# How to return an iText PDF document to the client side

Tags: java, gwt, itext

I am trying to return an iText generated PDF from the server side to the client side to enable the user to store it. I am following [How to convert iTextPDF Document to Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897290/how-to-convert-itextpdf-document-to-byte-array) (AceFunk)

```
private static ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  public static byte[] main(java.util.List<Transcript> listymAwards, String scoutName, String groupName) {
  Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

try {

  //PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream);  // Do this BEFORE document.open()

  document.open();
  addMetaData(document);
  addImages(document);
  addTitlePage(document, scoutName);

  //Add the table of achievements
  if (listymAwards == null || listymAwards.isEmpty()) {
      //Nothing to do.
      //System.out.println("Scout not found.");
  }else{

      Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();

      PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
      table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 3, 1});
      table.setHeaderRows(1);

      PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Section"));
      c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
      table.addCell(c1);

      c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Award"));
      c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
      table.addCell(c1);

      c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date"));
      c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
      table.addCell(c1);
      table.setHeaderRows(1);

      String storedName = null;
      int noRows = 0;
      String firstTable = "Yes";
      DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
      DateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
      // We add three empty lines
      addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
      addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
      addEmptyLine(preface, 1);

      for (final Transcript scoutNamesDescription : listymAwards) {
          if (firstTable.equals("Yes") && noRows > 30){ // Change this to number of rows required
              noRows = 0;
              firstTable = "No";
              document.add(table);
              document.newPage();
              table.flushContent();
          }else{
              if (firstTable.equals("No") && noRows > 50){ // Change this to number of rows required
                  // We add three empty lines if not the first table
                  document.add(preface);
              }
          }

          noRows++;

          if (scoutNamesDescription.getSection().equals(storedName)){
              table.addCell(" ");
          }else{
              storedName = scoutNamesDescription.getSection();
              table.addCell(scoutNamesDescription.getSection());
          }
          table.addCell(scoutNamesDescription.getAwardName());

          Date awardedDate = df1.parse(scoutNamesDescription.getAwardedDate());
          String awardedString = df2.format(awardedDate);
          table.addCell(awardedString);
      }
      //Print the remaining rows.
      // We add three empty lines if not the first table
      if (firstTable.equals("No")){
          document.add(preface);
      }else{
          firstTable = "No";
      }
      document.add(table);
  }

  //Add signature
  addSignaturePage(document, groupName);

  document.close();


} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

byte[] pdfBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
return pdfBytes;
```

}

This is returned to the server side:

```
    byte[] pdfBytes = ScoutTranscript.main(listymAwards, scoutName, groupName);
    System.out.println("Point 3");

    return pdfBytes;
```

Which is then returned to the client side:

```
Window.open("data:application/pdf;base64,"+result,"_parent", "location=no");
```

Where I get the error message:

```
This site can’t be reached

The webpage at data:application/pdf;base64,[B@154 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

Comment: Do you get this message right away or after some time?

Comment: The message is displayed fairly quickly.

Comment: You are not using a Servlet to provide the pdf? What are you using (RequestFactory/GWT-RPC) to transfer the content of the pdf? I would recommend to use a HttpServlet, then you just have to write your byte array to the ServletOutputStream and set the correct headers for the http response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Error #1:**

Let's start with a small test that doesn't involve iText in any way. Try this:

```
byte[] test = "Test".getBytes();
System.out.println("Test " + test);
```

What is written to the output? In my case, it's:

```
Test [B@3da3da69
```

The `[` indicates that I am trying to convert an array to a `String`; the `B` indicates that the array contains bytes; the `@` separates the type from the ID; the characters that follow are the ID in hexadecimal format (a hashcode). See [Java: Syntax and meaning behind "[B@1ef9157"? Binary/Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040868/java-syntax-and-meaning-behind-b1ef9157-binary-address)

If `result` is of type `byte[]` and you have this line:

```
Window.open("data:application/pdf;base64,"+result,"_parent", "location=no");
```

Then `"data:application/pdf;base64,"+result` results in something like `"data:application/pdf;base64,[B@154"`. That doesn't make any sense, does it?

Now try this:

```
byte[] test = "Test".getBytes();
System.out.println("Test " + new String(test));
```

The output is:

```
Test Test
```

You were using a `byte[]` as if it was a `String`. This is your first error.

I was going to say something nasty because this is not an error that a Java developer would make. However, I've just read your bio, and I see that you're new at Java and you are (probably) teaching yourself how to code in Java (just like I did 20 years ago), so I censored myself ;-)

**Error #2:**

You can not solve your problem by replacing your code by:

```
Window.open("data:application/pdf;base64,"+ new String(result),"_parent", "location=no");
```

You can't do that because you are making a second error: the bytes in `result` represent a *binary file*, and the JavaScript in your browser expects a Base64 encoded file. Base64 encoding is used to convert binary to text, and vice-versa. See [What is base 64 encoding used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201479/what-is-base-64-encoding-used-for)

If you want to send the binary PDF file to the browser as a Base64-encoded string, you have to Base64 encode your bytes. This can be done with this class: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/codec/Base64.html

For instance:

```
Window.open("data:application/pdf;base64,"+ Base64.encodeBytes(result),"_parent", "location=no");
```

This should already work for some browsers, but not for all. I have no idea where you are using `Window.open()`, nor why you want to involve Base64. You may want to elaborate on that. In my opinion, it's a bad idea.

**How it should be done:**

Typically, you will write a `Servlet` that runs in an application server. That servlet can be reached from a browser using a URL. **You do not need to save the generated file on the server** as suggested in the other answer (I down-voted that answer because it is not helpful and totally wrong). Your approach that creates a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then gets a `byte[]` is correct, but you have to serve those bytes to a `HttpServletResponse` object.

See [How can I serve a PDF to a browser without storing a file on the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456901/how-can-i-serve-a-pdf-to-a-browser-without-storing-a-file-on-the-server-side) for a full example.

**Regarding Window.open()**

You can use `Window.open()` on the client side, to open a web page in a new window. For instance:

```
window.open("http://www.itextpdf.com");
```

You can serve a page that has contains this snippet, but in your case, you have to replace `http://www.itextpdf.com` with the URL that was defined for your servlet.

You may have found your "solution" here: [Opening PDF String in new window with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805330/opening-pdf-string-in-new-window-with-javascript)

But if you read the comments, you'll notice that this approach is problematic in combination with some browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much Bruno this is very generous of you. I have carefully read this and the links and changed my code. I now need to know how to call as I have three parameters the first of which is a string. Please see my post below.

Comment: You have used an answer to post a new question. That goes against the rules on Stack Overflow. You should post a new question. It seems that you want to post `param1` as an array through a HTTP request, but you're doing it the wrong way. I'm answering from my phone (which makes ik harder to search), but I'm sure someone has already answered this. I'll post a link to that answer once I have time to spend at my computer.

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061273/send-an-array-with-an-http-get (you'll have to change you code; a `String.format()` won't be sufficient.)

Comment: OK. Thank you Bruno. I thought that as they all related to the same issue, which is not completely resolved yet, that would be OK. I will follow these instructions and raise new posts for each issue including a link back to here.